# Filter by exact match in phpunit

Tags: php, phpunit

The `--filter` option for phpunit does a fuzzy match. Let's say I have a test called `testHandle` and another test called `testHandleFooBar`. How can I run only `testHandle` using the `--filter` option?

Comment: `--filter '/::testHandle$/'`? Not posting this as an answer cause I'm unfamiliar with that flag. This is a guess based on [the docs](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/7.4/textui.html#command-line-options).

Comment: @Jeto That worked, thanks, if you post it as an answer I will accept

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Per [the docs](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/7.4/textui.html#command-line-options):

> `--filter`
>
> Only runs tests whose name matches the given regular expression
>   pattern. If the pattern is not enclosed in delimiters, PHPUnit will
>   enclose the pattern in / delimiters.

The basic format for a test method filter is the following:

```
TestNamespace\TestCaseClass::testMethod
```

So, by doing:

```
--filter '/::testHandle$/'
```

It will match only a method whose name is exactly `testHandle`, since the `$` character matches the end of a string in a regular expression.